# Use custom font in PHP Mail

Tags: php, email, fonts

I'm using Mailjet as email API for Laravel and I can send emails without issues but can't change the font family. Here's what I do:

```
$content = '<html dir="rtl"><body style="direction: rtl; text-align: right; 
font-family: DroidArabicKufi">';

$params = array(
     "method" => "POST",
     "FromEmail" => "info@domain.com",
     "FromName" => $sitename,
     "Subject" => "SUBJECT HERE",
     "Html-Part" => $content,
     "Text-Part" => "PLAIN TEXT HERE",
     "Recipients" => $to
   );
```

This is the same font of the website so users browse the website and this font gets downloaded to their devices but it's not working. Font is not changed.

How can I use this font in the email message

Comment: Are you sure that they have `DroidArabicKufi` Try using a font they are  more likely  to have and see if that works, then you will know if the method is good, but the font is missing or if the method itself does not work

Comment: it's the website font so it should have been downloaded to their devices once they visit the website right? I have this font installed but it's not changed in the email messages I send to myself for testing

Comment: body, a, li, label{font-family: 'DroidArabicKufi'; } from website css file

Comment: Do you mean its your website font ?? That does not mean the MailGun will have that font available! As they are building the email, they would have to have access to that font within there own system. _Thats not guaranteed_

Comment: And unless they pass the fonts on to the recipient of the email when the email is read on my machine I wont have access to that font anyway

Comment: so Mailjet need to enable or add that font. not enough to use it in my website